# Keyframes not storing the movement of vertices

Tags: rendering, animation

I'm trying to animate a helicopter's blades rotating, but the keyframes aren't storing the vertice's movement. It just changes the vertices of all the keyframes for that object.

Comment: could you please show some screenshots? you can't keyframes vertices except with shapekeys

Comment: what r shape keys? btw i started using blender like 3 days ago

Comment: @nicasso Shape Keys are basically how you rig objects a. To do it for individual vertexes there is no tutorial you can learn it as it's not too hard.